# Cropping images in Javascript (IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, crop

Is there a way to manipulate an image(crop) using javascript in IE? I know that I can do this with some ActiveX controls. But is there a pure javascript way? May be with filters are any special api provided by Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what you're trying to do.  You can use a containing div with `overflow` set to `hidden` and a constrained size to clip off any portion of an image and only show a desired crop.  If the geometry is known ahead of time, this can be done with pure HTML/CSS.  If you need to calculate the size, then sizes, positions and CSS properties can be set with javascript.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QsHy7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Jcrop` with the [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) library. ([info](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/), [download page](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/))

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at iCropper: http://github.com/supnate/icropper which is a pure javascript image cropping solution. It doesn't depend on any library which makes it fast, light-weight and easy to integrate.